# Is there an environment variable in vscode which returns the opened folder's name?

Tags: visual-studio-code

You can use the `${workspaceRoot}` in `settings.json`. But is there an environment variable which returns the opened folder's name?

Pseudo code example:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/../virtualenvs/${openedFolderName}/bin/python"
}
```

Also, is all environment variables you can use defined somewhere in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs)? I can't find anything on that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes: `${workspaceRootFolderName}`

So, this code would work:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/../virtualenvs/${workspaceRootFolderName}/bin/python"
}
```

I found this under the documentation on tasks: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution